# Custom CSV (.csv) filter for OpenOffice.org or LibreOffice?

Tags: openoffice, csv, spreadsheet, libreoffice

Is it possible to create a some kind of 'custom CSV filter' for OpenOffice.org or LibreOffice spreadsheet program. What I need is to have the program to use predefined CSV settings for loading and saving when I open, let's say file named 'somefile.myext'. Also I would need the loaded data to be placed in a prestyled spreadsheet.

In this particular case, I would need the CSV settings to have tab as a field delimiter and no text delimiter at all. Prestyled spreadsheet would contain Blue gray coloring for every odd row (achieved with conditional formatting formula), some font styling and probably some column width definitions.

Comment: almost sounds like you want to be able to create a program to take csv datasheets and format them into the style you want. This questions should probably goto SO and not SU.

Answer (score 0):

You need a database then. CSV files are plain text, and therefore don't carry formatting. You can try to create a template, then import the data through Copy-Paste on another window, and tell it to use Destination Formatting